# How to print print timestamp in format [2023-07-05 15:00:07.680973] inside C code

Tags: c

How to print timestamp in format [2023-07-05 15:00:07.680973]?

Comment: The fractional seconds might be an issue, but in general `strftime()`.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Then read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to show a [mre] of ***your own*** attempt, together with a detailed description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: You have stated what the format of the desired output is, but not what the format of the input is. In what format is the time stored, that is to be printed? Is it in [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t)? Is it in [`struct tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm)? Or are you storing `year`, `month`, `day`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` in separate variables?

Comment: Or are you asking how to get the time in such a format that it can be printed as shown in your question?

Comment: Please explain why `printf("[2023-07-05 15:00:07.680973]");` is not a solution. I ask this to illustrate that the interesting question is only how to get a certain source of the time-stamp to print in that format, with some tricky problem you have encountered. So please give details. Maybe you can show a [mre] of what you did and point out in which way it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to print the local time with microseconds:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timespec ts;
    // Modify the timespec object pointed to by ts to hold the current
    // calendar time in the time base TIME_UTC:
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);

    // Convert given time since epoch (a time_t value) into calendar time, expressed
    // in local time, in the struct tm format:
    struct tm lt = *localtime(&ts.tv_sec);

    char buff[100];

    // Convert the date and time information from a the calendar time `lt` to a string:
    strftime(buff, sizeof buff, "%F %T", &lt);

    printf("[%s.%06ld]\n", buff, ts.tv_nsec/1000);
}
```

Read:

- [`timespec_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get)
- [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime)
- [`struct tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm)
- [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime)